# Apply set function in pandas columns with ordered set element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[101,'QA'],
           [101, 'DEMO'],
           [102, 'PAGF'],
           [103, 'DC1'],
           [103, 'RA6'],
           [103, 'DC1'],
           [103, 'PA4']
          ]
          , columns=['Call_id', 'skill_desc'])
```

output:

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame([[101,'QA,DEMO','QA,DEMO'],
           [102, 'PAGF','PAGF'],
           [103, 'DC1,RA6,DC1,PA4','DC1,RA6,PA4']
          ]
          , columns=['Call_id', 'skill_desc_combined','Ordered_Skill_set'])
```

I want to merge the skill_desc with ',' for each call id and need set of skill with ordered elements in Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `dict.fromkeys` for unique values:

```
g = df1.groupby('Call_id')['skill_desc']
df1['skill_desc_combined'] = g.transform(','.join)
df1['Ordered_Skill_set'] = g.transform(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
```

Or aggregate in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with tuples and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys())
df = df1.groupby('Call_id')['skill_desc'].agg([('skill_desc_combined',','.join), 
                                               ('Ordered_Skill_set',f)])
```

Alternative with named aggregations:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys())
df = df1.groupby('Call_id').agg(skill_desc_combined=('skill_desc',','.join),
                                Ordered_Skill_set=('skill_desc',f))
```

---

```
df1 = df1.join(df, on='Call_id')
print (df1)
   Call_id skill_desc skill_desc_combined Ordered_Skill_set
0      101         QA             QA,DEMO           QA,DEMO
1      101       DEMO             QA,DEMO           QA,DEMO
2      102       PAGF                PAGF              PAGF
3      103        DC1     DC1,RA6,DC1,PA4       DC1,RA6,PA4
4      103        RA6     DC1,RA6,DC1,PA4       DC1,RA6,PA4
5      103        DC1     DC1,RA6,DC1,PA4       DC1,RA6,PA4
6      103        PA4     DC1,RA6,DC1,PA4       DC1,RA6,PA4
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Kindly have a look on below url. Need your help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127203/compare-the-two-rows-string-for-same-id-and-get-the-unique-string-values-in-pand