# compare the two rows string for same id and get the unique string values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[101, 'DC1', '  AHT  - QA +  + AHT - Required Disclosures + payment'],
               [101, 'EM5', ' AHT  -  QA + AHT - Required Disclosures + + Off + STAR.ist'],
               [102, 'RA6', '+ AHT - QA + Recap Warning - Yes +'],
               [103, 'DC1', 'Greeting + NavigateToView +'],
               [103, 'RA6', 'PaymentSelection +  Button Eligible +'],
               [104, 'PA4', 'Legal task + advice'],
               [104, 'DC1', 'Legal task + advice']
              ]
              , columns=['Call_id', 'Agent_id', 'Task_done'])
```

Expected output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([[101, 'DC1', '  AHT  - QA + + AHT - Required Disclosures + payment','payment'],
               [101, 'EM5', ' AHT  - QA +  AHT - Required Disclosures + + Off + STAR.ist',' Off + STAR.ist'],
               [102, 'RA6', '+ AHT - QA + Recap Warning - Yes +','+ AHT - QA + Recap Warning - Yes +'],
               [103, 'DC1', 'Greeting + NavigateToView +','Greeting + NavigateToView +'],
               [103, 'RA6', 'PaymentSelection + Button Eligible +','PaymentSelection + Button Eligible +'],
               [104, 'PA4', 'Legal task + advice','same task'],
               [104, 'DC1', 'Legal task + advice','same task']
              ]
              , columns=['Call_id', 'Agent_id', 'Task_done','unique_task_done'])
```

I have merged the multiple task_done for agent_id from different table with delimiter '+' and Now, I want to compare the Task_done for same call_id with different agent_id and get the unique string in another column Python 3.6 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df1['unique_task_done']=df1['Task_done'].mask(df1['Task_done'].duplicated(keep=False),'same task')  
mask=df1['unique_task_done'].str.count(' + ')
```

Finally:

```
df1.loc[mask.ge(2),'unique_task_done']=df1.loc[mask.ge(2),'unique_task_done'].str.split('+').str[mask.max():].str.join('+')
```

Now If you print `df1` you will get your output